# bash script to ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

```
[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || die "3 arguments required, $# provided"          
echo $1 | grep -E -q '^[0-9][0-9].0.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]' || die "Numerical drop number required, $1 provided"    
echo $2 | grep -E -q '^[0-9][0-9].0.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]' || die "Numerical drop number required, $2 provided"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

fail "3 arguments required, #{ARGV.length} provided" unless ARGV.length == 3
fail "Numerical drop number required, #{ARGV[0]} provided" unless ARGV[0] =~ /^[0-9]{2}.0.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/
fail "Numerical drop number required, #{ARGV[1]} provided" unless ARGV[1] =~ /^[0-9]{2}.0.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/

# profit???
```

Comment: Try `/^[0-9]{2}.0.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/`.

Comment: Sure, I changed it.  I suspect the `.`s should be escaped, but I think this is equivalent to what was posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

`
[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || die "3 arguments required, $# provided"          
echo $1 | grep -E -q '^[0-9][0-9].0.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]' || die "Numerical drop number required, $1 provided"    
echo $2 | grep -E -q '^[0-9][0-9].0.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]' || die "Numerical drop number required, $2 provided"
`
```

:D